# Cannot Login to SP Site from application Server - Login prompt continually

Tags: security, web-application, iis, host-header, host-named

After Creating new Site Collection root(SPWEB) with Host Header every request made from server (internal) is denied (Popup login Window continually). If requests come from FE (same USER), access is granted.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be victim of **LoopBackCheck**.

Possible solutions:

- Bypassing your proxy server for local addresses ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750194.aspx#XSLTsection122121120120))
- Adding a team Web site to the list of trusted intranet sites ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750194.aspx#XSLTsection123121120120))
- SharePoint disable loopback check (DisableLoopbackCheck dword in registry)([Source](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/05/24/sharepoint-disable-loopback-check-disableloopbackcheck-dword-in-registry/))

For me `DisableLoopbackCheck` worked.

Comment: +1 To improve your post, use the title of your references instead of disclosing links as the anonymous 'Source'. Thank you!